# Four values ​in two fields：a b ；bc，how to Merge into one field abc

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  userid      department_from        department_to 
   1                a                  b
   1                b                  c
   1                c                  d
   2               aa                 bb
```

I want to get

```
userid    department_trans
1          a→b→c→d
2          aa→bb
```

in oracle

Comment: Use recursive CTE for gathering the paths then select the row with the longest path per userid.

Comment: What happens if a user returns to the same department?

Comment: Note: _Columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

Would hierarchical query do any good? Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query begins at line #11.

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (userid, department_from, department_to)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 1, 'a', 'b' FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 1, 'b', 'c' FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 1, 'c', 'd' FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 2, 'aa', 'bb' FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT userid, result
 12    FROM (    SELECT userid,
 13                     LTRIM (
 14                           SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (department_from, '->')
 15                        || '->'
 16                        || department_to,
 17                        '->') result,
 18                     ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) rn
 19                FROM test
 20          CONNECT BY department_from = PRIOR department_to)
 21   WHERE rn = 1;

    USERID RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 a->b->c->d
         2 aa->bb

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem has been solved and I have learned new knowledge